# homologous recombination and non-homologous recombination ratio during S-phase

Tags: genetics, molecular-genetics, cell-division, cell-cycle

Can I assume that it is easier to do targeted gene knock-in in rapidly dividing cells because they should have a short period of G1? Is there an easy way to measure the relative amounts of homologous recombination (HR) and non-homologous end joining (NHEJ) during the S and G2 phases? Is HR favored over NHEJ during S-phase for all cell types?